# No much for argument: nvidia , No much for argument: current , Error: Unable to find a match

Tags: fedora, terminal, drivers, nvidia, dnf

I recently have installed fedora 27.
I wanted to install drivers for graphic and so on . I used this command line

> sudo dnf install invidia current

And this error appears :

> No much for argument: nvidia 
>   No much for argument: current
>   Error: Unable to find a match

Answer (score 0):

These errors means that the OS recognizes your command as a try to install nvidia and to install current... And so, doesn't find any of these two and fails to install.

1) try with nvidia-current (with the dash between)

2) If your pc seems ok without any drivers (but the default open source), DO NOT INSTALL ANY. This is no windows... In linux as more closed source you use, so more possibilities you have to be in troubles soon or later.